# How to install GLIBC 2.29 or higher in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, glibc

So I am trying to install truDesk on my local system. I am getting this error while running the command `npm install -g yarn`:

> node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found
> (required by node)

My Ubuntu version is **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS** and when I am checking for the latest version, it's showing that the software is up to date. As I go through the glibcc error, it requires an Ubuntu version greater than 18. How can I update the version?

This is the [**application**](https://docs.trudesk.io/v1/guide/installation.html#Linux-Install) I am trying to download.

Answer (score 22):

You can try to download `glibc` from the official source and install it:

```bash
wget -c https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.29.tar.gz
tar -zxvf glibc-2.29.tar.gz
mkdir glibc-2.29/build
cd glibc-2.29/build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc
make 
make install
```

Pay attention to avoid breaking your OS environment: you need to specify the prefix and configure the separate path when you are using it.

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) on how to use the alternate GLIBC.

Comment: after make receive : Makeconfig:42: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: @Amir do not run `./configure` in same folder with sources. Make new folder for `./configure` files with `mkdir ../glibc-build` and `cd ../glibc-build` to it. Then run `../glibc-2.29/configure --prefix=/opt/glibc` from the **source** while staying in _glibc-build_ folder. And finally `make && make install`

Comment: @Alexey, after doing that it looked solved but after, I tried to run `yarn` in my project but got `node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)` immediately again.  Is there more steps `make && make install`?

Comment: @rom There is no compiled version of GLIBC version 2.28 for version of linux kernel (`5.4.0-132-generic`) in Ubuntu 18.04. If You will compile `GLIBC_2.28` from sources and put it in system lib folder, its just crush your system with "Segmentation Fault", and after hard shutdown - stops booting...
Solutions: upgrade your your OS, or compile more recent kernel, then compile all required libraries.

Comment: this answer lacks the instructions how to use the new compiled library with the application

Comment: the `make` command take forever long for me...

Answer (score 14):

Answer from @Dolphin isn't complete as it produces error from make: `Makeconfig:42: *** missing separator. Stop.`

In my case, to I had to do following:

```bash
# Check GLIBC_2.29
ldd --version | head -n1

# Build GLIBC_2.29 from sources
sudo apt-get install gawk bison -y
wget -c https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.34.tar.gz
tar -zxvf glibc-2.34.tar.gz && cd glibc-2.34
mkdir glibc-build && cd glibc-build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.34
make 
sudo make install
```

P.S. If you are trying to run `ord` just try building from sources, it's much simpler than upgrading ubuntu or recompiling GLIBC

Comment: Apparently I need to update gmake to run the ../configure. I get "These critical programs are missing or too old: make", not sure how to solve. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry but did not work even after reboot and `ldd -version` check.

Comment: @Alex I got this error: *** These critical programs are missing or too old: make compiler, on Centos 7

Comment: I am trying to install glibc 2.39 on ubuntu 22.04. Did not work for me as well. Everything is going well with running `sudo make install`, but post that when I run ldd --version it points to the older version, i.e 2.35