# Getting GLIBC_2.28 not found

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I running the **node -v** command, getting the error:

> node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

[image: An image of the a terminal window. node -v returns the above output. Additionally, sudo apt-get install libc6 indicates the package is already installed at version 2.27-3ubuntu1.5.]

Is there a solution?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72921215/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 94):

Finally I got solution by running the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
nvm install 16.15.1
```

Node.js v16.15.1 version and npm v16.15.1 is installed.
For the same, make sure nvm is installed in your machine.

Comment: Yes!  Instead of 18 or 19, use 16.  This worked for me.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked after 2 days of scrounging for an answer.  Had high hopes in this answer to solve it but it still didn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513993/how-to-install-glibc-2-29-or-higher-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: I know this will work, my problem is I'm on the latest setup of libraries and everything and I don't want to downgrade simply because my ec2 instance can't keep up, has anyone else found any other solution other than downgrading? It would require me to downgrade on a bunch of stuff including alot of my core libraries like react, etc.

Answer (score 73):

You can install Node.js v17.x by **nvm** (Node.js version manager).

My OS version: [Ubuntu 18.04.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) LTS (Bionic Beaver)

I tried three ways to install Node.js and npm on my pc:

1. (**fail**) [apt-get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)). The version is very old

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install nodejs
   $ sudo apt-get install npm
   $ node -v
   v8.10.0

   $ npm -v
   6.1.0
   ```
2. (**fail**) script from source code of Node.js, only Node.js is updated, npm is not.
   https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#using-ubuntu-1

   ```
   $ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x -o /tmp/nodesource14_setup.sh
   $ node -v
   v14.20.1

   $ npm -v
   6.1.0
   ```
3. (**success**) use nvm

   https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get remove nodejs
   $ sudo apt-get remove npm

   $ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
   $ chmod +x ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
   $ source ~/.bashrc

   $ nvm -v
   0.39.2

   $ nvm install 14

   $ node -v
   v14.20.1
   $ npm -v
   6.14.17

   $ nvm install 16

   $ node -v
   v16.18.0

   $ npm -v
   8.19.2

   $ nvm install 17

   $ node -v
   v17.9.1

   $ npm -v
   8.11.0

   # Failed to install 18
   $ nvm install 18

   $ node -v
   node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

   $ npm -v
   node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
   ```

Comment: Node 18.12 is now the LTS (as of 2022-10-25) and because of its dependency on older glibc, I cannot use it.  We have GLIBC v2.34 installed and I see the same error reported here. I can no longer use "nvm install --lts".  Instead, I create .nvmrc file with "lts/gallium", which will install the previous LTS (16.18.0).

Comment: This is a really good answer, it solved my problem.  In my case I had to downgrade to Nodejs v12.

Comment: nice sunshine LOL thanks

Answer (score 54):

I'd had the same problem when installing Node.js with versions greater than or equal to 18.
My solution was upgrade my distribution Ubuntu to version [20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)), followings the steps:

##### My requirements before upgrade:

- Node.js (v18.x)
- Windows 10
- [WSL 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux#WSL_2) (distribution [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver))

#### Making a backup from your WSL system (for your security)

If you don't use WSL you can skip the steps:

1. Open CMD or PowerShell as Admin.
2. Stop the WSL instance with `wsl --shutdown`
3. Create the folder `wsl-backup` with the command `mkdir C:\wsl-backup\`.
4. Run command `wsl --export Ubuntu-18.04 C:\wsl-backup\ubuntu-18.04.tar`.

If there is a problem in the process, you can restore your WSL using the command `mkdir C:\WSL` and `wsl --import Ubuntu-18.04 C:\WSL C:\wsl-backup\ubuntu-18.04.tar` to recover.

### Upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

1. Removing the Snapd package:

   For me it was necessary to remove the `snapd` package, because Ubuntu was not allowing me to upgrade to the 20.04 LTS version

   ```
   sudo apt purge snapd
   ```
2. Run commands to update and upgrade packages:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt list --upgradable
   sudo apt upgrade -y
   ```
3. Install the `update-manager-core` package:

   It’s essential to install this update manager core package this will trick the system into thinking there is a new LTS available and allow you to do an in-place upgrade.

   ```
   sudo apt install update-manager-core
   ```
4. Install the new version with:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

   If you are using an LTS version (recommended) and found that there is no new LTS version available it will show this message

   ```
   Checking for a new Ubuntu release
   There is no development version of an LTS available.
   To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
   set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
   ```

   If it's not relevant to you to not use LTS versions, you can change the Prompt to normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file and rerun the previous command.

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade -d
   ```
5. During installation, will need your interaction to allow installation of the additional packages that come in version 20.04 (including lib6 that is required by Node.js).
6. Finished, now can verify your distribution version  Ubuntu using the command:

   ```
   lsb_release -a
   ```

   You should get an output similar to this

   ```
   Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
   Release:    20.04
   Codename:    focal
   ```

Now you can use Node.js version 18 or later

#### Install Node.js 18 with NVM

Installing Node.js LTS

In the current date (2022-11-26) is v18

```
nvm install lts
# Or nvm install --lts
```

Use the LTS version

```
nvm use lts
```

Check the Node.js version

```
node -v
# v18.12.1
```

##### References:

- [Upgrade Ubuntu Version on WSL](https://dev.to/equiman/upgrade-ubuntu-version-on-wsl-3h10)
- [22.04 LTS "sudo do-release-upgrade" does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403616/22-04-lts-sudo-do-release-upgrade-does-not-work)
- [Can't upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04 : "Restoring original system state. Aborting"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344069/cant-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-04-restoring-original-system-state-aborting)

Comment: Even if Trevor was a bit faster regarding the Ubuntu update (which is the better option than downgrading node, imho), your answer is more detailed.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had to run `do-release-upgrade` twice, and in the middle append this to the end  of `/etc/apt/sources.list` because of error _"No valid sources.list entry found"_ https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1#file-sources-list

Comment: ...and I needed to use `nvm install --lts` instead (note `--`).

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade` kept telling me I had just installed a package that requires a reboot of my system. Since I'm using wsl, I went into services and restarted LxssManager.

Comment: Upgrading Ubuntu was the only solution that fixed this issue for me! Thanks

Answer (score 40):

You got the issue because the Node.js version is not compatible with Ubuntu. In my case, I got the same issue with [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) and Node.js 16.15.1.

Using this command to check the [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) version:

```
ldd --version
```

My version is 2.27. So I have tried to fix it by changing the Node.js version.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
nvm install 14.17.6
```

Comment: ldd --version was very helpful. I updated WSL2 to the latest version and then ldd command showed me Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1, so I installed Node 16.14.0 and it works since then.

Comment: Just to inform future visitors that, Ubuntu 18.04 (glibc 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) does work with Node 16.17.0

Answer (score 13):

The root cause is the latest Node.js needs [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) 2.28, but [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) only includes glic 2.27.

Solution: 1. use a lower version Node.js, e.g., "sudo apt-get remove nodejs nvm install 16.15.1". Refer to [Abhay Kumar Upadhyay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921215/getting-glibc-2-28-not-found/72937118#72937118).

Solution 2: upgrade glibc to glic 2.28+. Refer to:  *[How install GLIBC 2.29 or higher in Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-install-glibc-2-29-or-higher-in-ubuntu-18-04)*

Solution 3: upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Refer to [Hállex da S. Costa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921215/getting-glibc-2-28-not-found/74586477#74586477).

Comment: I've just checked the link on the solution 2, and it seems the solution proposed there  is to upgrade the OS or to build (compile and pack) on your own. I'm quite disappointed with that...

Answer (score 10):

It means the current version of Linux doesn't have [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) 2.28 which the latest version of Node.js requires.

You can run the `ldd --version` command to check your glibc version.

**`ldd --version`**

You can fix this in two ways:

1. Install an older, more widely supported version of Node.js (16.X).
2. Upgrade your Linux operating system to a newer version.

Just changing your Node.js version to 16 is the fastest solution and it worked for me.

```
nvm install 16
nvm use 16
```

If you don't have NVM (Node Version Manager), then install using:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 8):

### GitHub Actions

I ended up here after my [GitHub Actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub#Scope) build failed with the error:

> node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)

The problem is Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) not supporting Node.js 18 (as explained [here] (node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by Node.js))) because of the glibc version bump.

The solution is to update to Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) or higher.

Answer (score 2):

You likely have a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) version installed that is compiled for a different Ubuntu release to the one you are running.

I would suggest removing it, and then installing the [nodesource binary distribution](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall). It should auto-detect your Ubuntu release and install the correct Node.js release.

Comment: thx for your answer. how would i remove it?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others to remove and reinstall Node.js, but if you don't want to uninstall it or you are not sure to remove it, change the version.

```
nvm use 16
```

Or any version that works for your test. It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I've just managed to get Node.js 20 working on an [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) instance, by compiling my own version of [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) v2.28, installing it to `/opt/glibc-2.28` and using `patchelf` to patch `/usr/local/bin/node` to use it. It works like a charm, and building glibc takes much less time than building Node.js. Instructions (on a [Jetson Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Jetson#Versions), so the architecture-related details will vary):

```
sudo -i

# Start by installing Node.js 20:

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tj/n/master/bin/n -o n
bash n 20

# Node.js 20 is now at /usr/local/bin/node, but glibc 2.28 is missing:
# node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
# /usr/local/bin/node: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/node)

# Build and install glibc 2.28:
apt install -y gawk
cd ~
wget -c https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.28.tar.gz
tar -zxf glibc-2.28.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.28
./configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.28
make -j 4 # Use all 4 Jetson Nano cores for much faster building
make install
cd ..
rm -fr glibc-2.28 glibc-2.28.tar.gz

# Patch the installed Node.js 20 to work with /opt/glibc-2.28 instead:
apt install -y patchelf
patchelf --set-interpreter /opt/glibc-2.28/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 --set-rpath /opt/glibc-2.28/lib/:/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ /usr/local/bin/node

# Et voilà:
node --version
v20.8.0
```

I've also posted this on GitHub:
*[NodeJS 18 not working on Ubuntu 18.04 #1392](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1392#issuecomment-1749131791)*

Answer (score 0):

As [per ys_sunshine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921215/getting-glibc-2-28-not-found/74236389#74236389), I had change a few things for [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi).

After installing the LTS version as per the following instructions:
*[Installing Node.js on the Raspberry Pi](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-nodejs/)*

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -
```

I got the following error:

```
node -v
```

Output:

```
node: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

This meant I couldn't run anything, so I tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get remove npm

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh > install.sh
chmod +x install.sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

Outputs:

```
$ nvm -v
0.39.2

$ nvm install 14

$ node -v
v14.22.2

$ npm -v
6.14.17
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the only solution that helped me: *[How can I fix issue "node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
version 'GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)"?](https://dev.to/abbazs/how-to-fix-issue-node-libx8664-linux-gnulibcso6-version-glibc228-not-found-required-by-node-3chb)*

Install nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
```

Configure nvm in the [$HOME/.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example) file:

```
check=' export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"'
if ! grep -qF "$check" ~/.bashrc; then
    echo "" >>~/.bashrc
    echo "# Add NVM to path" >>~/.bashrc
    echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >>~/.bashrc
    echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >>~/.bashrc
    echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"' >>~/.bashrc
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question because I was trying to use Visual Studio Code and Codium with the remote SSH extension to connect to a Ubuntu 18.04 system. When it failed I discovered the GLIBC_2.28 error in the remote system extension logs.

Downgrading node on the remote doesn't help because [the](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) [extensions](https://github.com/jeanp413/open-remote-ssh) download their own node binary.

The ugly hack which fixed it for me was to replace that downloaded node binary with a symlink to the locally installed own node:

```
cd $HOME/.vscodium-server/bin/<UUID>
mv node node.broken
ln -s /usr/bin/node
```

Replace `.vscodium-server` and `<UUID>` as required.

Caveat this is likely to break when the SSH remote extension next updates, and will need to be reapplied.

Answer (score -1):

In certain situations where you have moved everything to a new machine and not rebuilt your *[node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder)* folder, this can happen.

In your project folder run this:

```
npm rebuild
```

This isn't always the case, but it is possibly this.

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs due to unsupported versions of node for certain older versions of Ubuntu.

All the solutions are pointed to nvm (per user installation), but you can also use `n` for system-wide installation.

In the present case (Ubuntu 18.04) for the current error we need version 16 of node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 16
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy     # fix path /usr/bin/node
```

Answer (score -3):

This issue can be resolved by switching to stable available Node.js version. You can switch to the stable Node.js version with the below command.

```
nvm install --lts
```

Then, Use `nvm alias default {VERSION}` to switch the version of Node.js used by default when starting a new shell.

Answer (score -5):

Remove Node.js:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

Install NVM on [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)), [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)), and [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) with the command:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh
bash install.sh
```

After the installation, [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)#Source) the profile:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Verify the NVM installation:

```
nvm -v
```

With NVM, you can also list the installed Node.js versions with the command:

```
nvm install 16.15.1
```

Switch to a preferred version of Node.js:

```
 nvm use 16
```

You can as well make the version default.

```
nvm alias default 16
```