# How to link node 18.12.1 with glibc 2.28 at runtime?

Tags: node.js, glibc

I installed glibc 2.28 on my Linux Mint 19.1 system successfully by following [How to install GLIBC 2.29 or higher in Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513993/how-to-install-glibc-2-29-or-higher-in-ubuntu-18-04).

Now I need to actually run `node`. The new glibc has been installed in /opt/glibc. How to make sure node links with glibc 2.28.

Comment: I think you have build nodejs from source since path for glibc is defined inside the binary (I am assuming you downloaded nodejs from archive).