# `GLIBC_2.34' not found at start Flutter app in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, glibc, drift

I made (build release) Flutter app in Linux Mint 21.2 and app is run ok. And app is run ok in Ubuntu 22.04. But in **Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04** I have got errors:

```
./dkc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./dkc)
./dkc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/alex/Рабочий стол/Linux release 20231207/lib/libsqlite3_flutter_libs_plugin.so)
./dkc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /home/alex/Рабочий стол/Linux release 20231207/lib/libsqlite3_flutter_libs_plugin.so)
./dkc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/alex/Рабочий стол/Linux release 20231207/lib/libsqlite3_flutter_libs_plugin.so)
./dkc: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /home/alex/Рабочий стол/Linux release 20231207/lib/libsqlite3_flutter_libs_plugin.so)
```

My pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.5 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  connectivity_plus: ^5.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  darq: ^2.0.0
  device_info_plus: ^9.1.1
  dio: ^5.4.0
  docx_template: ^0.4.0
  drift: ^2.14.1
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  excel: ^4.0.0
  file_picker: ^6.1.1
  flutter_window_close: ^1.0.0
  get: ^4.6.6
  intl: ^0.19.0
  package_info_plus: ^5.0.1
  package_rename: ^1.5.0
  path: ^1.8.3
  path_provider: ^2.1.1
  pdf: ^3.10.6
  printing: ^5.11.1
  sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.5.18

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^2.4.7
  drift_dev: ^2.14.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
```

Ubuntu 18.04 bash:

```
apt policy libc6
libc6:
  Установлен: 2.27-3ubuntu1.6
  Кандидат:   2.27-3ubuntu1.6
  Таблица версий:
 *** 2.27-3ubuntu1.6 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.27-3ubuntu1.5 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.27-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

How can I resolve errors?
Thanks.

Tried to update **libc6**, but new version not found.
Tried to use [How to install GLIBC 2.29 or higher in Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72513993/how-to-install-glibc-2-29-or-higher-in-ubuntu-18-04), but not helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I resolve errors?

The easiest way to resolve this is to build your application on the *lowest* version of GLIBC you plan to support (Ubuntu 18.04 here).

If you can't do that, you would need to make your application use alternate (non-system) installation of GLIBC, which is complicated and fraught with peril when done incorrectly.

> Tried to use How to install GLIBC 2.29 or higher in Ubuntu 18.04, but not helped me.

That answer tells you how to install GLIBC into `/opt/glibc` and then redirects to a different answer on how to make your application *use* that newly-installed version.

I am guessing you've skipped the second step.